# Create CSS overlay over youtube player to prevent clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm experimenting with embedding youtube videos, and am hoping to create a video that users *can't* interact with. I've managed to remove all the ui stuff, but can't seem to prevent clicking. I stumbled upon a website that is doing [exactly what I want to do](http://soundtube.xyz): on the bottom right, there is a youtube video with an apparent overlay that prevents clicking; it seems simple enough but I can't figure it out! Any advice would much appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <div id="player"></div>

  <script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

     // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube     player)
     //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    var start = 30;
    var end = 35;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '250',
        width: '400',
        videoId: 'BalUcQpYN6k',

        playerVars: {
          'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 0,
          'disablekb': 1,
          'start': start,
          'end': end,
          'fs': 0,
          'iv_load_policy': 3,
          'loop': 0,
          'modestbranding': 1,
          'showinfo': 0,
          'rel': 0
        }

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this to your css.

```
#player {pointer-events: none;}
```

```css
#player {pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <div id="player"></div>

  <script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

     // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube     player)
     //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    var start = 30;
    var end = 35;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '250',
        width: '400',
        videoId: 'iRkCIuY2pHc',

        playerVars: {
          'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 0,
          'disablekb': 1,
          'start': start,
          'end': end,
          'fs': 0,
          'iv_load_policy': 3,
          'loop': 0,
          'modestbranding': 1,
          'showinfo': 0,
          'rel': 0
        }

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**I dont know how I ended up back here a year later** but out of curious I went and looked up the OP's link and `pointer-events: none` is exactly what they are using, as shown below.

```
.player-container > .modal-inner-container > #player, .player-container > .modal-inner-container #html5-player, .lyrics-container > .modal-inner-container > #player, .lyrics-container > .modal-inner-container #html5-player {
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update HTML with a bit more:

```
 <div id="playArea">
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="yt-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And add this CSS:

```
.yt-overlay, .#playArea > .yt-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: This is what that looks like:  

 `<body>

  <style>
    .yt-overlay, .#playArea > .yt-overlay {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

  </style>
    <div id="playArea">

    <div id="player"></div>

    <div class="yt-overlay"></div>

    </div>`



Apologies for the poor formatting. Anyway, I have inserted this into the code, to seemingly no effect. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place a block element before the player. (`#shield`)
2. Next wrap both `#shield` and `#player` in a block element. (`#main`)
3. The important part is `#main` is `position:relative` and it's children elements are `position:absolute` with the overlay (`#shield`) having a higher `z-index` than the `#player`.
4. The rest of the Snippet should be self-explanatory.

**SNIPPET**

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#shield {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background: transparent;
}
#player {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
  <main id='main'>
    <section id='shield'></section>
    <div id="player"></div>
  </main>
  <script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    var start = 30;
    var end = 35;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '250',
        width: '400',
        videoId: 'BalUcQpYN6k',

        playerVars: {
          'autoplay': 1,
          'controls': 0,
          'disablekb': 1,
          'start': start,
          'end': end,
          'fs': 0,
          'iv_load_policy': 3,
          'loop': 0,
          'modestbranding': 1,
          'showinfo': 0,
          'rel': 0
        }

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```